# How to create matrices that are subsets of larger matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm learning matlab.  I'd like to create a smaller array from a larger one.  I know how to do this with simple columns or rows, but I get lost in the nomenclature for `m x n` arrays / matrices.

Original matrix = 10 x 9 
     `mat_original=ones(10,9)`  in fact, rather than use all ones.. this may make more sense.. lets use `mat_original = magic(10)`

How do I create a component matrix say with rows 5 to 8 (all columns)?
       `mat_rows5to8 = mat_original[5 thru 8; :]`

How do I create a component matrix, say with columns 2 to 5, (all rows?)
     `mat_cols2to5 = mat_original[: ; 2 thru 5 ]`

and finally how would I create a sub-component array... say rows 4 thru 7, and columns 5 thru 9 ?
     `mat_small = mat_original[ 4 thru 7; 5 thru 9 ]`

How do you remember this stuff?

Comment: @AndrasDeak, why the downgrade?  Was this statement absolutely unhelpful, and that poorly written?  (Should I provide all the search terms I used to not find an answer before posting here?  Remember, you can only be a Matlab virgin once... Matlab virgins use generic search terms from very generalized fields, not necessarily the same search terms used by seasoned veterans...)  Am I just better off deleting this whole question or does it have value to others in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to remember things when you have Google: [Matrix Indexing in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).

Answers to your questions:

1. `mat_rows5to10 = mat_original(5:8,:)`
2. `mat_cols2to5 = mat_original(:,2:5)`
3. `mat_small = mat_original(4:7,5:9)`

In other words:

- `output = input(<row_first>:<row_last>,<col_first>:<col_last>)`
- Leave any of the parameters out to include all.

Comment: Thx, I kept getting stuck at the [obtuse matlab help pages](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html)

Comment: Ah, yeah, sometimes it's better to read documents written for beginners, as technical documents aim for comprehensiveness (and lose beginners).

Comment: I never realized there is a timer on the check mark as an acceptable answer.  Seems to be set at 15 minutes.

Comment: No worries; glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Also, there's the special index `end` as in `mat_original(end:-2:1,:)` to get every other row in reverse order. And @zipzit: [this is the manual page you need](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html). (MATLAB's help is unconventionally helpful most of the time, so if you're stuck, and even searching on SO doesn't help: it's usually your fault.)